# How do I send dynamic content to Triggered Sends?

Tags: fuel-sdk

How do I send dynamic content to Triggered Sends? 
I just have only one field that is dynamic, "someToken". 
Can I set email like below? If not, how can I add "someToken" to the email?

`ETClient client = new ETClient("fuelsdk.properties");
ETTriggeredEmail triggeredEmail = new ETTriggeredEmail();
triggeredEmail.setClient(client);
triggeredEmail.setKey("222");
// Can I set email or will this use the email associated with this triggered email?
ETEmail email = new ETEmail();
email.setSubject("Testing");
email.setTextBody("Here is your token:" + "someToken");
triggeredEmail.setEmail(email);
//
ETResponse results = triggeredEmail.send("aa@abc.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to use Data Extensions with Trigger Send. 
When you create a Trigger Send, make sure to select the Data Extension and you can use this fields in the Data Extension in the Email object.
ie.
Add "someToken" column in Data Extension "tokenDataExtension". 
Select "tokenDataExtension" in your TriggerSend and you can use %%someToken%% in the Email object.